# How to add a list of card views in Android with only one of them removable by swiping?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to make a card list on the Main Activity of my app, and I want the user to have the ability to delete the first card, as it is only informative. The rest of the cards would then open layouts that correspond to them.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Roman Nurik's Android-SwipeToDismiss: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss

Implementation example is here: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/MainActivity.java

Now in dismiss callback enable dismiss only on the first element.

```
new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    ...

});
```

*Not sure if the second element becomes the one at the position 0. If that's so you also need to track if the header was dismissed. Anyways, you can start from this and work it out.*

Comment: I'm completely lost as to how to add set items with set strings values, not just generic numbers.

Comment: @overhound the whole CardView implementation is not trivial.. you can start here: http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/ and then adapt it to your need.. feel free to PM if you get stuck somewhere

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to pm you so I sent you a message on Google+ if you don't mind.